# Convert a binary dump back to text in vi?

Tags: xxd

Select text in vim and convert it to a hex dump...

```
:'<,'>!xxd
```

(Note 2 hex characters represent a single letter...in whatever encoding I did this in...)

Select a hex dump in vim and convert it back to text...

```
:'<,'>!xxd -r
```

Select text in vim and convert it to a binary dump...

```
:'<,'>!xxd -b
```

How do you convert it back from the binary dump?

Comment: Does `xxd -r` or `xxd -br` work? I haven’t tried it, but... PS you might be interested in my plugin [hex](https://github.com/benknoble/vim-hex)

Comment: `xxd` man page -b option says : `The command line switches -r, -p, -i do not work with this mode.`

Comment: @dedowsdi unfortunate

Answer (score -1):

xxd version 1.10 ("xxd V1.10 27oct98 by Juergen Weigert (Win32)") states

> xxd --help [...] Options: [...] -b binary digit dump (incompatible with -ps,-i,-r). Default hex.

@dedowsdi also pointed out the reverse operation with a binary dump does not work with xxd. It does not look like it can be done with xxd. Therefore I have come up with some alternative ways:

### Option 1: vim dictionary-like method

I guess this could be call a dictionary method. Here are (I think) all of the non-control characters of ASCII without any tab character:

```
32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58
59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85
86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108
109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126
```

ASCII 32-126 (decimal) equals all of the characters on a QWERTY keyboard:

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

Run this in vim (binary dump must match the `/........ ........ ......../` type pattern with a space between each 8 binary numbers):

```
:%s/00100001/!/ge | %s/00100010/"/ge | %s/00100011/#/ge | %s/00100100/$/ge | %s/00100101/%/ge | %s/00100110/\&/ge | %s/00101100/,/ge | %s/00110010/2/ge | %s/00111000/8/ge | %s/00111110/>/ge | %s/01000100/D/ge | %s/01001010/J/ge | %s/01010000/P/ge | %s/01010110/V/ge | %s/01011100/\\/ge | %s/01100010/b/ge | %s/01101000/h/ge | %s/01101110/n/ge | %s/01110100/t/ge | %s/00100111/'/ge | %s/00101101/-/ge | %s/00110011/3/ge | %s/00111001/9/ge | %s/00111111/?/ge | %s/01000101/E/ge | %s/01001011/K/ge | %s/01010001/Q/ge | %s/01010111/W/ge | %s/01011101/]/ge | %s/01100011/c/ge | %s/01101001/i/ge | %s/01101111/o/ge | %s/01110101/u/ge | %s/00101000/(/ge | %s/00101110/./ge | %s/00110100/4/ge | %s/00111010/:/ge | %s/01000000/@/ge | %s/01000110/F/ge | %s/01001100/L/ge | %s/01010010/R/ge | %s/01011000/X/ge | %s/01011110/^/ge | %s/01100100/d/ge | %s/01101010/j/ge | %s/01110000/p/ge | %s/01110110/v/ge | %s/00101001/)/ge | %s/00101111/\//ge | %s/00110101/5/ge | %s/00111011/;/ge | %s/01000001/A/ge | %s/01000111/G/ge | %s/01001101/M/ge | %s/01010011/S/ge | %s/01011001/Y/ge | %s/01011111/_/ge | %s/01100101/e/ge | %s/01101011/k/ge | %s/01110001/q/ge | %s/01110111/w/ge | %s/00101010/*/ge | %s/00110000/0/ge | %s/00110110/6/ge | %s/00111100/</ge | %s/01000010/B/ge | %s/01001000/H/ge | %s/01001110/N/ge | %s/01010100/T/ge | %s/01011010/Z/ge | %s/01100000/`/ge | %s/01100110/f/ge | %s/01101100/l/ge | %s/01110010/r/ge | %s/01111000/x/ge | %s/00101011/+/ge | %s/00110001/1/ge | %s/00110111/7/ge | %s/00111101/=/ge | %s/01000011/C/ge | %s/01001001/I/ge | %s/01001111/O/ge | %s/01010101/U/ge | %s/01011011/[/ge | %s/01100001/a/ge | %s/01100111/g/ge | %s/01101101/m/ge | %s/01110011/s/ge | %s/01111001/y/ge | %s/01111010/z/ge | %s/01111011/{/ge | %s/01111100/\|/ge | %s/01111101/}/ge | %s/01111110/~/ge | %s/\s//ge | %s/00100000/ /ge
```

### Option 2: use JavaScript and HTML

Render the following simple html file with your binary dump as a string in the `binaryAgent` function. It will work with all of ASCII, the tab character, and probably also extended ASCII and maybe Unicode.

```html
<script>
//From
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21354235/converting-binary-to-text-using-javascript
function binaryAgent(str) {
  var binString = '';
  str.split(' ').map(function(bin) {
    binString += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(bin, 2));
  });
  return binString;
}
document.write(binaryAgent('01110010 01100111 00110010 00110011'));
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! You might want to learn how to [edit] using Markdown formatting for readability.